# chrome extension - find text on website and apply CSS and hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been doing some research for this topic and can't find a valid link or any information on how to get this to function.

Effectively, I have a file called `text.txt` and I'd like to search through the text file on the website and apply a css styling and hover event on the word if it is found.

Manifest:

```
"name": "Find and apply testing...",
"description": "Testing",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],
"background": [{
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js"]
}]
```

I tried writing a js script that loops through a file, but I don't think it works properly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function readTextFile(file) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    console.log(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("file.txt");
});
```

Finally my `text.txt` file:

```
"Example Text", "http://google.com"
"Second Text", "http://example.com"
"Third", "http://another.com"
"And finally forth", "http://andanother.com"
```

I just need to search a site for the first cell. Any thoughts or guides? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.. I found that this worked pretty well for getting text from a website:

```
function getText() {
    return document.body.innerText;
}

if (getText().indexOf("searching") > -1) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("searching", "g"), "<span class='spanDetected' id='spanDetected'>" + 'searching'+"</span>");
    console.log("true");
}
```